# git custom stats definition via script and http sever

Tags: git, bash, statistics

I need a tool that allows me to hook (or poll for) commits and generate web stats for each commit.

I want statistics to be defined by ME not the tool. In principle something like this would be great:

1. a user performs a new commit/push
2. after a period of time (like 10 minutes or something), the tool checks out any new commits
3. for each new commit, the tool launches a user defined script that compiles all the statistics (e.g. to give an idea I'm particularly interested in a C++ project output sections size (.text/bss/data ...) and saves them in some way (txt file or database or whatever.. in the form "commit hash column, stat1 column, stat2, ... )
4. when I open the browser at severname:4567 a web interface shows me the graph of my stats (e.g. for each commit gives me the compiled output's .text and .data size).

Buildbot is the closed stuff I found but is no good for stats, only for compile failures and (I think) only for svn.

Is there anything suitable for saving my day?

Regards,
R

Answer (score 1):

Buildbot can do this.  It supports all sorts of version control systems, and can run whatever script you want, including one that compiles statistics and saves them somewhere.

What Buildbot will not do for you is display the statistics -- you'll need to build your own app for that purpose.  But such an app should get along nicely with Buildbot.